# How can ISP be prevented from remotely accessing modem?

Tags: router, modem, isp

How can I prevent At&t from messing with the modem?

Backstory:

At&t seems to have updated the firmware on the Arris NVG599 modem and all the settings were lost. After updating the static IP's on the subnet and getting my home server back up and running I tried to reconfigure the wifi, but the interface no longer works.

They set a catch 22 where I can't save different ssid/passwords for the 2.4 and 5.0 antennas and I can't toggle between the 2.4 and 5.0 settings without saving. It means I'm restricted to only use the default ssid and password and every device in my house now has to be redone.

I started chat with tech support and someone with poor English skills going by the name of John kept asking for personal details when all I want are instructions. I told him explicitly not to remotely change anything on the modem. Only a moment later he remotely rebooted the modem.

Every time at&t touches the modem they take a couple extra hours out of my life.

How can I prevent At&t from messing with the modem? They're really messing with my life here and all I want is for them to stop.

**Update:**
Is there no way to get root access to the an at&t modem? Maybe some way to bypass it entirely? If neither of those can be answered, can someone say how at&t techs access the device?

Comment: As long as you're leasing the modem from them it's not your modem; it's their modem. If you don't want this to keep happening, purchase your own modem.

Comment: I don't think At&t has that option. I wouldn't have any problem using my own modem.

Comment: Oh wow, I was under the impression most ISPs let you opt out of using their supplied modem. And here I was thinking about switching over to AT&T fiber. Guess I won't be doing that now.

Comment: @n8te, the ATT guys keep telling me, a network engineer, that my (enterprise-grade) router with SPF ports cannot connect to fiber, even though we use the same routers in my company that connect to ATT fiber. I tried to explain that I can get the correct SFP for the fiber, but they tell me that I can't, and that it is too technical for me. :) needless to ay, I don't use ATT.

Comment: @RonMaupin - well I hope you, the network engineer, deferred to the wisdom of the customer service rep :P

Comment: Their whole point is to make you rent a 5$-modem for 8$/month. I went through that fight too.

Comment: Simple solution: use the AT&T *"modem"* as just a modem (in bridged mode?), and get your own wireless router (that will be fully under your control and immune to ISP updates/control).

Comment: @n8te, of course I did - I just told them that I can't use their service because it isn't compatible with my equipment. :) They are now tearing up my yard, and the entire neighborhood, putting in new fiber because they are getting the 1 Gbps pressure from other ISPs. We'll see what happens in a few months.

Comment: @sawdust. I thought about that but a modem reset would lose the bridge mode. If At&t does some firmware update then I'm still stuck messing with their modem trying to fix static ips and reentering bridge mode.It does save on the wifi hassles.

Comment: I keep an old laptop [circa 2004] just for this one event - ISP changes or resets the modem/router. Unplug entire network, directly connect laptop set for just this purpose, reset router to pure modem mode, reconnect network, put laptop away until next time. Enjoy interference-free existence.

Comment: Connect router to modem, any configuration changes to modem, don’t effect router.  AT&T does indeed allow you to purchase a modem and use it yourself, however, they will still put firmware on your modem (you want this to happen because it’s required when they update your service)

Comment: “Maybe some way to bypass it entirely? If neither of those can be answered, can someone say how at&t techs access the device?” Access is provided by the firmware, firmware is required, for the device to work your service